# How to make external switch control LED stm32f4 board?

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller, stm32f4discovery

I tried to control the LED on board using external switch on breadboard but it does not?  The switch is connected to port d number 9, i tried to make it so that once i press a switch, the green LED comes on. But for some strange reason it does not work, i tried to fiddle around with it but no luck. How could i fix it so that it works?

Here is my code:

```
include <stdio.h>
include "STM32F4xx.h"
void Soft_Delay(void);
void LED_Init_1(void); 
void Push_button (void);
#define ITM_Port8(n)    (*((volatile unsigned char *)(0xE0000000+4*n)))
#define ITM_Port16(n)   (*((volatile unsigned short*)(0xE0000000+4*n)))
#define ITM_Port32(n)   (*((volatile unsigned long *)(0xE0000000+4*n)))
#define DEMCR           (*((volatile unsigned long *)(0xE000EDFC)))
#define TRCENA          0x01000000
struct __FILE { int handle;  };
FILE __stdout;
FILE __stdin;
int fputc(int ch, FILE *f) {
  if (DEMCR & TRCENA) {
    while (ITM_Port32(0) == 0);
    ITM_Port8(0) = ch;
  }
  return(ch);
}
int main (void) {

  LED_Init_1();
    Push_button ();

  while(1) 
        {  

if((GPIOD->IDR &= ~  (1UL <<   9))==1)
{
GPIOD->ODR |= (1UL <<   12);    

}    
    else if((GPIOD->IDR &= ~  (1UL <<   9))==0)
    {   

            GPIOD->ODR &= ~(1UL <<   12);                           


    }

}

}
void LED_Init_1 (void) {
  RCC->AHB1ENR    |= ((1UL <<  3) );            
  GPIOD->MODER    &= ~((3UL << 2*12));              
  GPIOD->MODER    |=  ((1UL << 2*12)  ); 
  GPIOD->OTYPER   &= ~((1UL <<   12) );             
  GPIOD->OSPEEDR  &= ~((3UL << 2*12) );         
  GPIOD->OSPEEDR  |=  ((2UL << 2*12) ); 
  GPIOD->PUPDR    &= ~((3UL << 2*12) );             
  GPIOD->PUPDR    |=  ((1UL << 2*12) ); 
}
void Push_button (void) {
    RCC->AHB1ENR      |= ((1UL <<  3) );            
  GPIOD->MODER    &= ~((3UL << 9));             
}
void Soft_Delay(void) {

    uint32_t i=10000000;  
    while(i>0)  
    {
        i--;  
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: First, make sure the green LED works properly without the switch. Make it blink by toggling it in a loop with delays.

Comment: The green LED does work, i have been doing it without the switch, now i'm including the switch but does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at this line (one of two similar) which seems to be checking the input:

```
if((GPIOD->IDR &= ~  (1UL <<   9))==1)
```

Firstly I dispute why you are writing the port value back with `&=`

Secondly, why would an input on bit 9 equate with `1`?

Thirdly, the `else` testing (apparently) for the opposite state is superfluous - a plain `else` will do. I don't have your system or tools, so I am guessing this code.

```
if((GPIOD->IDR & (1UL << 9)) != 0)
    GPIOD->ODR |= (1UL << 12);    
else
    GPIOD->ODR &= ~(1UL << 12);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that helped :)